# Java Swing Program is not running on command prompt

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My java swing code compiled successfully but its not executing from cmd

```
package swing_1;
public class JavaCalculator implements ActionListener{
```

the above class contains the main method

when i'm compiling there's no error showing `javac JavaCalculator.java`

but when I trying to execute `javac JavaCalculator.java`

its showing

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JavaCalculator
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: swing_1/JavaCalculator (wrong name: JavaCalculator)
```

Comment: Post all code and the error and we can help.

Comment: 1.) There are only two lines of the code. 2.) Please add the cmd line you used to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you are missing a manifest. Try calling it this way:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2
```

where the latter part is the location of your Class that contains the main method

Answer (score 0):

That is because you should compile in the directory where the subdirectory `swing_1` resides:

```
javac swing_1/JavaCalculator.java

java -cp . swing_1/JavaCalculator.class
```

Start with an IDE like NetBeans or IntelliJ (community) or eclipse.

Comment: Without using IDE how to execute that

Comment: The package path lists the directory hierarchy for the java sources. You have to be in the root with the command-line.

Comment: I have added the class path specification; probably is needed too.